# DataTables : search field position misaligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm currently making a small website using JSP and DataTables (only for the 1st table at the moment). 
 
Here is what I have so far : 
[image: illustration of the problem with the search field position]

As you can see, There is a positional problem of the search field. I really don't know what is causing this. What I would like to have, is the end of the search field not going further than the border of the bottom table.

Here is my HTML :

```
<TABLE class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="usertable" style="max-width: 800px">
<thead>
        <TR>
            <Th colspan=2 align=center><FONT color="blue">Toto</font><br>
                <i> (toto@toto.be) </i><b><FONT color = "red">Administrateur</b></font>
            </Th>
            <Th colspan=1 align=center><a href="UserUpdate?action=update&id=2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><FONT color="green"><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                </span> Editer mon compte</FONT>
                </button></a>
            </Th>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <Th width=40% align="center"><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Date de la pêche</Th>
            <Th width=40% align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Poids du poisson (Kg)</Th>
            <Th width=20% align="center"><i>Action</i></Th>
        </TR>
</thead>

<tbody>
        <TR>
            <TD width=40% align="center">03-07-2014</TD>
            <TD width=40% align="center">24.0</TD>
            <TD width=20% align=center><a href="FlightUpdate?action=delete&idvol=1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Ok pour supprimer le vol ?')">
                <FONT color="purple"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Supprimer pêche</FONT>
                </button></a></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD width=40% align="center">22-08-2014</TD>
            <TD width=40% align="center">42.0</TD>
            <TD width=20% align=center><a href="FlightUpdate?action=delete&idvol=2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Ok pour supprimer le vol ?')">
                <FONT color="purple"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Supprimer pêche</FONT>
                </button></a></TD>  
        </TR>
</tbody>
</TABLE>
```

And my JS selector :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#usertable').dataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"fp<"clear">>rt'
    } );
      //$('.carousel').carousel();
});
</script>
```

Of course, I'm using the JQuery libraries :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>         
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Is there something I can do to have the sDom correctly aligned ? 

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data tables search box will expand the entire width of the display area, which in your example is the entire with of the view port.  In order to correct this you will need to have a wrapper ( or ) that sets the max with of the area the table will use.

```
 <div style="max-width: 800px">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="usertable" style="max-width: 800px">
     ........
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: That was so simple... Why didn't I think about that earlier :-)
Thanks a lot, works perfectly !